# Node.js can't see ImageMagick on Windows 7

Tags: node.js, imagemagick

I Installed ImageMagick (ImageMagick-6.9.2-3-Q16-x64-static.exe) and add in my js file following:

```
var easyimg     = require('easyimage');
```

but when I start my node.js app I get this error:

ImageMagick Not Found
EasyImage requires ImageMagick to work. Install it from [Link](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the ImageMagick directory is in your path. Add it to your system or user PATH environment variable.

Test by opening a **new** command window and running the following:

```
cd C:\PATH\TO\NODE_PROJECT\
echo %PATH%
imdisplay.exe
```

The last step should launch a viewer which is in the imagemagick path.

If you set and verifed the path is correct then you should not get any error when your run:

```
node app.js
```

If that fails try removing everything except imagemagick from your path in case your edits have resulted in a **corrupt path**.

```
set PATH=C:\PATH\TO\IMAGEMAGICK
C:\PATH\TO\NODE\node.exe app.js
```

Comment: yes I read about this and install this thing but it doesn't help

Comment: I tested the fix. It worked for me by setting the path in the system menu but not when setting process.env in node. I will update the answer

Comment: in my path I already have ImageMagick and I try from console to convert image and all is ok, but from node.js I see the error.

Comment: open a new cmd window.  echo %PATH%. Make sure your path IS up to date. Like I say, I got the same error and it works for me now

Comment: C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.2-Q16;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\bin.........

Comment: @OlegBaranovsky : Made a final edit to the answer. Some effort required to install software, reproduce your error and then fix it. May I suggest you  test updated answer then accept, upvote or delete the question.

Answer (score 11):

In windows, rename file 'magick.exe' to 'convert.exe' will work.

Comment: This worked, I'd just recommend *copying* magick.exe as convert.exe

Comment: Worked for me as well. Windows 10, Node 6.9.1. The accepted answer (the steps, i had the env variables already defined) ran without a problem, but i wasn't getting the `GM` module (with a sub-classed `imagemagick`) to do some conversions. Renaming/copying magick.exe to convert.exe helped here.

Comment: Indeed, this fixed the issue at my end as well (Windows 10). Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

When you install ImageMagick, check the option `Install legacy utilities (e.g. convert)`.