# Error while using image-watermark in node.js

Tags: node.js, imagemagick, watermark

I am using `image-watermark` for adding watermark to a file on server side node.js and it is producing an error.

I tried installing modules `image-watermark`, `imagemagick`, and other dependencies. At first, I faced a problem similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46210448/image-watermark-nodejs-showing-error). But, this problem was resolved by installing **ImageMagick** into my system and now that is resolved from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43713441/7514132) answer.

Now, I am getting an error in the following code:

```
const watermark = require('image-watermark');
const imagePath = path.resolve(__dirname,'./relative/path/to/image');
watermark.embedWatermarkWithCb(imagePath, { 'text': 'sample watermark' }, 
function (err) {
    if (!err)
      console.log('Succefully embeded watermark');
    else {
      //I am getting error here.
      console.log(err);
    }
});
```

The image file should be exported with a watermark. But, instead I am getting this error:

```
{ Error: Command failed:
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous>(...\node_modules\imagemagick\imagemagick.js:88:15)
    at emitTwo (events.js:131:20)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit 
(internal/child_process.js:209:5) timedOut: false, killed: false, code: 1, 
signal: null }
```

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27883443/75141320) answer to get to the root cause of the error. Without that I got `Error: spawn ENOENT` error only.

Comment: just for discard, try the following: 

- sudo node your_app.js

Comment: @ene_salinas I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prepare a basic example for you:

[download the code here](https://github.com/ns4lin4s/stackoverflow/tree/master/56353310)

Pre-requisite:

```
install imagemagick in SO
install ghostscript in SO (for pdf files)
```

Ex. for mac:

```
brew install imagemagick
brew install ghostscript (for pdf files)
```

The steps are the following:

```
- You must enter the folder ./stackoverflow/56353310/

- npm install

- node index.js
```

The output must be something like that:

[image]

any question please let me know.

Comment: This works fine if I am using it on a different module. Also, this doesn't work for **pdf**

Comment: @SushantPaudel I edited the answer, basically you need to install ghostscript for pdf files, do you need anything for close this question? let me know.